# How to get tables to be created immediately in nested pl/sql block

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, block

I am creating tables, then taking the count of those tables and storing them in variables, all inside a nested pl/sql block on an Oracle database. I am getting error "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist". If I create the tables first, then run my block, it executes with no errors.

Therefore, I know the tables aren't being created, even though I am using the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command. (I thought this command would bypass the fact that all objects used in an PL/SQL block must exist BEFORE the PL/SQL block is executed.)

It will be difficult at this point to create the tables outside of my block, is there another way?

Sample code below:

```
DECLARE
  g_user varchar2(30) := 'schema';
BEGIN
  /* more code and nested blocks*/
  DECLARE
    v_Count_Task1A number(6);
  BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' ||g_user||'.T_Task1A_Roles_w_User_IDs  AS
    SELECT ROWNUM AS Dummy_Field, USUS_ID AS Task1A_Role, User_ID AS Task1A_User_ID
    FROM Task1A_Roles_w_User_IDs';

    SELECT count(1) INTO v_Count_Task1A
    FROM T_Task1A_Roles_w_User_IDs;
    /*more operations like this*/
  END;
  /* more code and nested blocks*/
END;
```

Comment: What's the reason behind why you're trying to do this? Typically, you wouldn't be creating tables in pl/sql - you should be doing it once at the database level and then using them in your code. Also, your code doesn't make much sense if `g_user` isn't the current schema.

Comment: the purpose is to just generate reports, "they" want all but 6 tables to exist only for when this gets run which would probably by nightly. I put `g_user` in there just for testing in my own schema in dev environment.

Comment: Wow. That's a lot of overhead in creating tables only to drop them again each night. It also makes the code way more complicated! What's the reasoning behind "them" wanting the tables only to exist for the duration of producing the reports? Are the tables even needed for the production of the reports? Can they be generated from single sql statements, rather than needing to store the data into another table first?

Comment: I agree, it feels overly complicated. This code is basically echoing an ACL script that needed to be converted to SQL, since they were kill and fill tables in ACL and it was working for them, I thought to just keep it that way. I think some tables might be unnecessary, but others are and since theres 50+ I decided not to try to weed every bit, at least not yet. I figure for now replicate what works, stand it up, then improve.

Comment: You'd be much better off with creating the tables once, and then - if absolutely required - populate / truncate. Or perhaps global temporary tables (GTTs) are better suited - data is stored in them for the duration of the transaction/session* on a session basis (ie. session a could insert data and session b wouldn't be able to see that data). You would be better off spending time working out the best way to make use of the database now rather than later, because we all know that there is never any time later because there's other stuff to do!   (*depending on how they're set up)

Comment: Is there a significant performance benefit from creating tables and then populate/truncate over kill and fill tables? or is it just more stable that way?

Comment: There will be benefits in performance (no overheads in creating/dropping the tables) but you've also got to consider things like parsing overheads (dropping and recreating the tables is going to affect what gets stored in the SGA) as well as things like well-designed code. In general, creating and dropping tables on the fly in pl/sql is indicative of poor database design (there are, of course, exceptions - but they're rare). You'll find your code easier to write and compile if the tables are permanently present.

Comment: Thanks for all the insight, I'm a pretty green DBA so I appreciate it, it's helpful. I'll keep this all in mind as I'm reconstructing this process

Comment: Not a problem! It's also worth bearing in mind that if you have a series of selects based on each table, you may well be able to combine them into one query by using sub queries. Use of the With clause (aka sub query factoring) may also prove useful. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't that your table doesn't get created when the block runs, the problem is that the table doesn't exist when the PL/SQL is compiled and so it can't be compiled and therefore cannot be run at all.

The solution here is to use more dynamic SQL to perform the count, since dynamic SQL is not parsed until execution of the block:

```
DECLARE
  g_user varchar2(30) := 'schema';
BEGIN
  /* more code and nested blocks*/
  DECLARE
    v_Count_Task1A number(6);
  BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' ||g_user||'.T_Task1A_Roles_w_User_IDs  AS
    SELECT ROWNUM AS Dummy_Field, USUS_ID AS Task1A_Role, User_ID AS Task1A_User_ID
    FROM Task1A_Roles_w_User_IDs';

    EXECUTE IMMEDATE 'SELECT count(1) FROM T_Task1A_Roles_w_User_IDs' 
        INTO v_Count_Task1A;
    /*more operations like this*/
  END;
  /* more code and nested blocks*/
END;
```

Comment: I love this site, nice explanation. Solution worked like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need `SELECT INTO` in dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE
  g_user varchar2(30) := 'schema';
BEGIN
  /* more code and nested blocks*/
  DECLARE
    v_Count_Task1A number(6);
  BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' ||g_user||'.T_Task1A_Roles_w_User_IDs  AS
    SELECT ROWNUM AS Dummy_Field, USUS_ID AS Task1A_Role, User_ID AS Task1A_User_ID
    FROM Task1A_Roles_w_User_IDs';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
    SELECT count(1) 
    FROM T_Task1A_Roles_w_User_IDs'
    INTO v_Count_Task1A;
    /*more operations like this*/
  END;
  /* more code and nested blocks*/
END;
```